# Cascades instrumentation amplifiers with a buffer in between stages: What should I use for buffer?

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation

I have to cascade two instrumentation amplifiers, INA126, and in between the stages I want to use a buffer.  How should I make the buffer? The output from the first INA126 is of few volts.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? An instrumentation amp is made specifically for amplifying small signals with large common-mode voltages; the output of an instrumentation amp, if it needs more amplification, is probably better amplified by an opamp.

Comment: What's the purpose of the buffer? Normally the output of an in-amp is low enough impedance that you can drive inputs extremely accurately even if they present a moderate load.

Answer (score 4):

I have never seen a reason to cascade two instrumentation amplifiers.  An instrumentation amplifier takes a differential signal as input, and transforms it to a single-ended ground referenced signal (with most of the common mode noise attenuated).  Once it comes out of the instrumentation amplifier, you can and should just use operational amplifiers for subsequent stages.

What the steps between the Instr. Amp. and the final output are depends upon what your signal looks like, and why you need to use a two stage approach in the first place, when IAs can provide very large gains all by themselves.  Often, you do this because there's a DC offset that you need to remove, and if you amplify in one stage, you'll just saturate the amplifier.    If this is the case, I like the instrumentation amp to provide modest gain, big enough to amplify but small enough not to saturate, and then on the output remove the DC with a high-pass filter (or with a potentiometer or subtraction circuit, if you need the low frequency response), and then amplify more with a noninverting amp.